# How to configure Jboss for two different ports?

Tags: java, apache-flex, jboss

I have a ear file and a war file,  need to deploy them in two different ports such as 8443 and 5480 respectively. How to configure two ports seperately for those two files. I have no experience configuring JBoss. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following similar question which provides the answer.

[Setting up multiple ports on a single JBoss instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171109/setting-up-multiple-ports-on-a-single-jboss-instance)

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of ports that JBoss might run on with one instance:

```
4248    0.0.0.0:1098
4248    0.0.0.0:1099
4248    0.0.0.0:26510
4248    0.0.0.0:3873
4248    0.0.0.0:4444
4248    0.0.0.0:4445
4248    0.0.0.0:4446
4248    0.0.0.0:4457
4248    0.0.0.0:4712
4248    0.0.0.0:4713
4248    0.0.0.0:53629
4248    0.0.0.0:53630
4248    0.0.0.0:8009
4248    0.0.0.0:8081
4248    0.0.0.0:8083
4248    0.0.0.0:9999
4248    127.0.0.1:53637
```