# Deploy Angularjs 1.5.X on JBoss App server

Tags: angularjs, jboss

Can Angularjs 1.5.X App directly deployed onto application server like JBoss 6.x. I have deployed Angularjs apps on Nginx, but I was wondering if AngularJS can be deployed to listen on different port on Same App server that also host the Rest API's developed using RestEasy on JBoss.

Does JBoss has ability to run Webapps?

Answer (score 3):

JBoss Application Server (AS) was a product developed by RedHat, currently replaced by [Wildfly](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/04/22/jboss_as_becomes_wildfly/), which, being a certified implementation of the [Java Enterprise Edition specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html), allowed the building, deploying, and hosting of highly-transactional Java applications and services.

Therefore, the answer to your question is yes. JBoss AS, as it name states, has the ability to serve web applications.

To deploy your AngularJS application on JBoss, I'd suggest you to create a web project and have it builded and packaged as a ready-to-deploy WAR archive using a build manager such as [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/).

As an example, you can follow the [kitchensink-angularjs](http://www.jboss.org/quickstarts/wfk/kitchensink-angularjs/) quickstart provided by JBoss.

Finally, regarding your AngularJS deployed on a different port question, you can find an answer to it in [How to run different apps on single JBoss AS 6 instance behind different ports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850228/how-to-run-different-apps-on-single-jboss-as-6-instance-behind-different-ports).