# Run the same JBoss server in two different ports

Tags: java, server, jboss, jboss6.x, jboss5.x

I want to execute my `java` web application (`ear` is deployed in the server) in the same `JBoss` server but in **two different ports**.

one is for **development** which would carry `8080` and other one which is for **QA testing** which would use `8180`.

Can someone please provide me guidence to do this with `JBoss` ?

I have tried out several ways but ended up getting errors.

I do not want to use two `JBoss` servers but to run the application in one `JBoss` server using two different ports. E.g. `8080` and `8180`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850228/how-to-run-different-apps-on-single-jboss-as-6-instance-behind-different-ports

Comment: Which JBoss version are you using?

Comment: JBoss 4 @SudhishNair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and testing so many ways I was able to find a way to deploy my `java` web application in `JBoss` server and run on **two ports** which are `8080` and `8180`.

*One JBoss server serving from two ports (8080 and 8180)*

Firstly, you need to build **QA EAR** and **Development EAR** accordingly.

Secondly, go to the `JBoss` Server location and find the following path.

```
D:\Servers\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server
```

In this location you need to create new server environment for QA, in my case I will name it as **server_uat**

[image]

Now the folder sturuture should display like above.

Copy following folders from `default` folder and paste it inside the `server_uat` folder,

- conf
- deploy
- lib

Now you can deploy the **QA** and **Dev** build to necessary to servers E.g. Dev build for **deploy** folder in **default** and QA build for **deploy** folder in **server_uat**.

Now go inside the `server_uat` folder and edit the following file which is in the following path

```
D:\Servers\jboss-4.2.3.GA_UAT\server\server_uat\conf\jboss-service.xml
```

Then search for this area in the XML file and start editing the mbean code fragment

```
 <!-- ==================================================================== -->
   <!-- Service Binding                                                      -->
   <!-- ==================================================================== -->
```

Edit should be done as follows.

```
<attribute name="ServerName">ports-01</attribute>
```

Add `ports-01` value into the `<attribute name="ServerName">________</attribute>`

```
ports-01 refers to 8180 port
ports-02 refers to 8280 port
ports-03 refers to 8380 port
```

These are defined by `JBoss` Server for the **ease of configuration**.

Once all done go to `D:\Servers\jboss-4.2.3.GA_UAT\bin` using Command Prompt and execute the `run.bat` file.

Then again open Command Prompt and execute `run.bat` file using following command to up and run newly created `server_uat` server instance

```
./run.bat -c server_uat
```

Now check application using both,

```
http://localhost:8080/login.do //Dev
http://localhost:8180/login.do //QA
```

`mbean` code fragment after the change

```
 <mbean code="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingManager"
     name="jboss.system:service=ServiceBindingManager">
     <attribute name="ServerName">ports-01</attribute>
     <attribute name="StoreURL">${jboss.home.url}/docs/examples/binding-manager/sample-bindings.xml</attribute>
     <attribute name="StoreFactoryClassName">
       org.jboss.services.binding.XMLServicesStoreFactory
     </attribute>
   </mbean>
```